# Silent option for read gets ignored?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I run a loop in a bash shell script until a key is pressed (Ctrl-C always seems cruel to me).
Although I use the -s option for `read`, the single character is shown in the terminal.
Why does the -s option for `read` not do what I expect!

```
until read -s -n 1 -t 0.01; do 
    echo -n "."
    sleep .5    # actual script code goes here
    done 
echo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because the key is being pressed while `sleep .5` is running rather than while `read` is.

In more detail: when this runs, `read -s -n 1 -t 0.01` puts the terminal in noecho mode... for 0.01 seconds, then it times out and turns echo back on. If you had typed a character in that 0.01 seconds, it wouldn't have been echoed, but you probably missed the window. Instead, you type it in while `sleep .5` is running, so it echoes. Then half a second later `read` runs again, turns echo off (too late!), reads the character out of the typeahead buffer, and finally turns echo back on.

(Note: the `echo` command and the echo terminal mode have no direct connection, other than that they both involve things being printed to the terminal.)

Solution: rather than counting on `read -s` to turn off echo, use `stty -echo` once at the beginning (and `stty echo` at the end to turn it back on). As Uncle Billy pointed out in the comments, it'd also be wise to add a `trap` to make sure the terminal's set back to normal if the script exits abnormally for some reason (e.g. Control-C):

```
trap 'stty echo' EXIT    # If script exits abnormally, fix terminal
stty -echo    # turn off echo
until read -n 1 -t 0.01; do
    echo -n "."
    sleep .5
done
echo
stty echo    # turn echo back on
```

(You could remove the `trap` afterward, but it's not important -- setting the terminal to what it should be anyway is a pretty safe operation.)

EDIT: as ilkkachu pointed out in the comments, it'd be better to remove the `sleep` entirely, and just use a longer timeout on the `read` -- that way when you press a key, it won't wait up to .5 seconds before noticing your keypress. You can also use a much longer timeout. I'd still keep use `stty -echo` to turn off echo rather than having `read -s` turn it off separately each time through:

```
trap 'stty echo' EXIT
stty -echo    # turn off echo
until read -n 1 -t 3600; do    # 1 hour timeout, 'cause why not
    echo -n "."
done
echo
stty echo    # turn echo back on
```

If you don't need the loop, you could just remove it entirely (in which case `read -s` should work fine):

```
read -s -n 1
```

Comment: maybe just `until read -s -n1 -t 0.5; do echo -n .; done` would do

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, dropping the `sleep` and having the delay only in `read` might be a good idea in that the loop would then actually exit immediately when a key was pressed. With the `sleep` there, it'd wait until the sleep is over, which is (barely) noticeable even with `sleep .5`. But would be more obvious with a longer sleep.

Comment: You should make an effort to also restore the stty settings when the script is killed by a signal. See what happens when you call it like `(trap 'echo DONE' INT; bash /that/script)` and press Control-C.

Comment: @ilkkachu Good points; I edited my answer with that option (plus just removing the timeout & loop entirely).

Comment: @UncleBilly Another very good point, and another edit.

Comment: I mostly meant that if you do just `until read -s -n1 -t 0.5; do echo -n .; done`, you still get the advancing dots, but even without the explicit `stty`s, the keypress is very likely not to be echoed, since the interval between the `read`s is short. I think that might help with having to restore the stty settings too, it looks to me that Bash resets the echo itself if the shell doing `read -s` is interrupted.

Comment: Wow, great feedback. But the echo -n "."; sleep .5 were just placeholders for my actual code. I should have mentioned that.